# Updating multiple rows with same value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table t with columns id(primary key),a,b,c,d. assume that the columns id,a,b and c are already populated. I want to set column d =md5(concat(b,c)). Now the issue is that this table contains millions of records and the unique combination of b and c is only a few thousands. I want to save the time required for computing md5 of same values. Is there a way in which I can update multiple rows of this table with the same value without computing the md5 again, something like this:

```
update t set d=md5(concat(b,c)) group by b,c;
```

As group by does not work with update statement.

Comment: please provide table ddl and what a,b,c contains. Is `a` unique/primary key?

Comment: Assume another primary key column is also present. a,b,c are all INT(11).

Comment: I figured out the actual cause for the large amount of time taken for the query. Since the column d was indexed, and this table was populated initially, updating the column d resulted in the index being recreated which was taking a majority of time in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpTable 
AS (SELECT b, c, md5(concat(b, c)) as d FROM t group by b, c)
```

Update initial table:

```
UPDATE t orig 
JOIN tmpTable tmp ON orig.b = tmp.b AND orig.c = tmp.c
SET orig.d = tmp.d
```

Drop the temp table:

```
DROP TABLE tmpTable
```

Comment: As I already commented on other answer, I have tried this and the joins are even more expensive as the columns are not indexed.

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select md5(concat(b, c)) as val
        from table t
        group by b, c
       ) tt
       on t.b = tt.b and t.c = tt.c
     set d = val;
```

However, it is quite possible that any working with the data would take longer than the `md5()` function, so doing the `update` directly could be feasible.

EDIT:

Actually, updating the entire table is likely to take time, just for the updates and logging.  I would suggest that you create another table entirely for the `b`/`c`/`d` values and join in the values when you need them.

Comment: Good solution. But as you said, I have tried this and the joins are even more expensive as the columns are not indexed.

Comment: @Abhay . . . You should normalize the data structure as a suggest in the edit.  Your problem may not be the MD5 function but simply the volume of updates.  A properly structured second table should be much faster.